# Address of deployed contract in hardhat

Tags: truffle, hardhat

Whenever you deploy a contract in truffle the generated abi is in build/contracts/contract.json. In this json there is also the address of the contract and I can import it in my other files.
In hardhat, is there somewhere the address of the deployed contract, or do I have hard code it in my code?

Comment: Consider using [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use what the contract variable is called to reference the address by writing `<variable name>.address`.

So if the variable you're using to store the contract info is `counter`. You'd reference `counter.address` whenever you want to use the address and can submit that as a parameter wherever it is needed.